# Fail to use self-signed certificate in Android

Tags: android, ssl, iis, https, ssl-certificate

It throws an exception like below

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

This Android program connects to my ASP.NET MVC deployed on IIS , and I create the `.csr` , .key , `.crt` file of my CA and my server's  certificate using OpenSSL.
And I convert the `.crt` file of my server's certificate to `.pfx` format and import it in IIS .

I found the solution on [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html) .But my code is similar to the code it lists .

```
 CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509","BC");

 InputStream caInput = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.root);  //here "R.raw.root" is a .bks file converted from my CA's .crt file , and a .bks file converted from my server's .crt file , but both throw this exception
 Certificate ca;
 try
{
     ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);

} finally

{
      caInput.close();
}

// Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
//String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

// Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
tmf.init(keyStore);

// Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(),null);

// Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext
URL url = new URL("https://172.18.13.178:63123/Home/Test");
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection =(HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

//omit other code
}
```

The Android Developer says this is the solution of this error , but I write my code similar to it , but it fails.

So anyone tell me where the problem is ? The way Android Develop gives does not work .

Comment: If your `minSdkVersion` is 24 or higher, use [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html). If your `minSdkVersion` is 17 through 23, try [my backport of network security configuration](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-netsecurity). Otherwise, AFAIK, the `setCertificateEntry("ca", ca)` is for setting a custom CA, not for a self-signed certificate. The code I used to use for self-signed certificates passed in the `InputStream` and keystore type to `load()` on the `KeyStore`.

Comment: @CommonsWare how  " The code I used to use for self-signed certificates passed in the `InputStream` and keystore type to `load()` on the `KeyStore` " ? Can you show me this line of code?

Comment: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/security/src/main/java/com/commonsware/cwac/security/trust/TrustManagers.java#L29-L56, which is called by https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/security/src/main/java/com/commonsware/cwac/security/trust/TrustManagerBuilder.java#L461-L496